# The name AudioLevelUpdated does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017, speech-to-text

I am a novice to C# i'm not sure if I'm writing on the right forum for this question . I am trying to implement a speech to text program. (winforms)
I moved Windows.cs.xml code to my program (Form1.cs) but I am facing this error

> 'The name AudioLevelUpdated does not exist in current context'

.
I tried adding assembly(System.Speech) and using directived but no improvement. plz help

here is  code

```
SpeechRecognitionEngine speechRecognitionEngine = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// list of predefined commands
    /// </summary>
    List<Word> words = new List<Word>();

    #endregion

    #region ctor

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Form1"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    //public event EventHandler<AudioLevelUpdatedEventArgs> AudioLevelUpdated;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        try
        {
            // create the engine
            speechRecognitionEngine = createSpeechEngine("de-DE");

            // hook to events
            speechRecognitionEngine.AudioLevelUpdated += new EventHandler<AudioLevelUpdatedEventArgs>(engine_AudioLevelUpdated);
            speechRecognitionEngine.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(engine_SpeechRecognized);

            // load dictionary
            loadGrammarAndCommands();

            // use the system's default microphone
            speechRecognitionEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

            // start listening
            speechRecognitionEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Voice recognition failed");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your code I see these two lines:

```
speechRecognitionEngine.AudioLevelUpdated += new EventHandler<AudioLevelUpdatedEventArgs>(engine_AudioLevelUpdated);
speechRecognitionEngine.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(engine_SpeechRecognized);
```

I'm not sure they're correct. At least I've never seen eventhandlers subscribed to in that format before. Edit: Just tried subscribing to events in this manner and it works. Seems overly verbose though!

Normally they would look like:

```
speechRecognitionEngine.AudioLevelUpdated += engine_AudioLevelUpdated;
speechRecognitionEngine.SpeechRecognized += engine_SpeechRecognized;
```

Then you would have handler methods:

```
private void engine_AudioLevelUpdated(object sender, AudioLevelUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    // Your code when the event fires.
}

private void engine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    // Your code when the event fires.
}
```

I don't see anywhere in your code that you have implemented these methods. Is that possibly where your error lies?

I've added System.Speech to a test application and instantiated a SpeechRecognitionEngine and subscribed to both events and the application starts up with no errors.

Comment: maybe you are right. I downloaded source code from code project and thats WPF project and its working with charms. But error occurred when I tried implementing that code in winforms

Comment: Winforms and WPF are very different. I'd strip out all the UI code you can find and just concentrate on the Speech stuff.